# How to open threedot option menu on click on custom imageview and custom menu using xml file inflator

Tags: android

How to open option menu like three dot using custom xml file inflator on click on custom imageview on action bar.

Answer (score 0):

On the onClick of your imageView implement the following code

```
     PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.tv_option);
            mContext.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.show();
```

item_menu is the xml file which includes your items in menu

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_rv_a"
    android:title="Test 1" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_rv_b"
    android:title="Test 2" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_rv_c"
    android:title="Test 3" /></menu>
```